# How to solve the error "Must use PackageReference"?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, windows-runtime

After adding `WindowsRuntime` to a WinForms-project, building the project fails with Error "Must use PackageReference". The build log is more precise:

> C:[...]\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Projectname\packages\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts.10.0.18362.2005\build\Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts.targets(4,5): error : Must use PackageReference

Here's what I did:

Install-Package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts

with references to:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll,
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.IO.dll
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll.

Is it maybe a thing with the .NET version? In the project's packages.config there is 4.6 while the project targets 4.5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts" version="10.0.18362.2005" targetFramework="net45"/>
<package id="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

There are no compile errors... only this strange "PackageReference" error.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to use net .core references in a System.Windows.Forms project?

Comment: Have you set, in `Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> General -> Package Management` to use `PackageReference` as Package management format? The 4.6 version is related to the `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` dependency, not the .Net Framework.

Comment: @Jimi, the error occurs when Default package management format is set to Packages.config as well as if it is set to PackageReference. I cleared the NuGet cache and the solution after changing this value.
When I installed Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts, the value was Packages.config... did I have to change the value before running Install-Package?

Comment: @bradbury9 , .NET Core is not involved. WinRT is said to be the new WinAPI and I need it to access [Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault).

Comment: Uninstall any NuGet packages related to `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts`, set `PackageReference` as default format, re-install all packages using NuGet Package Manager.

Comment: @Joe First reference is in a .net core named folder... `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`

Comment: @bradbury9 you are very mindful! I added the .NET Core library with despair but then figured out that the reference to the .NET4.5 library was sufficient... and somehow forgot to delete the .NET Core reference.

Comment: @Jimi thank you so much! Your advise worked.

Answer (score 145):

`VS2017/VS2019` ->  `Solution Explorer` -> *right-click* `References`  -> *"Migrate packages.config to PackageReference"*

`VS2019` ->  `Solution Explorer` -> *right-click* `packages.config` -> *"Migrate packages.config to PackageReference"*

I think this happens when you add a .NET core library to a .NET standard project.

Comment: I have installed using NuGet the new package Microsoft.Web.WebView2 and I have also installed Microsoft Edge Chromium. After that, I have rebuild application and I have receive “Must use PackageReference" error ! I have done Patrick proposal and build now work as before. Thanks

Comment: I was missing migration option in References context menu from VS2019, but it can also be found at packages.config context menu.

Answer (score 15):

Solution that worked for me was to:

1. Run a Clean on the project in question
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Navigate to the project folder on disk and delete the **obj** folder
4. Reopen Visual Studio and Build

Comment: There is a nuget package cache in the `obj` folder, which must be removed to clear that error message.

Answer (score 1):

Could be becuse of nugetpackage, for WPF use WPF one.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to your .csproj and remove the references to the package.
On my case they were at the end of the XML file

Comment: Yes that is,  this error happened to mi after install Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts and  I had to remove all reference in the file you mention