# Error while adding "WebView 6.0.0" to project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webview

I use WebView 5.1.1 (EdgeHTML) in my WPF project on .NET Framework 4.6.2. When I update to version 6.0.0, I get a error

**Must use packagereference.**

It happens to the Microsoft.Windows.Sdk.Contracts library, which appears when version 6.0.0 is installed.

How do I fix this?

And then there's the question.

When will WebView 2 (Chromium) be released on .NET C# WinForms or WPF?

Will there be differences from WebView (EdgeHTML)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the error "Must use PackageReference"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540212/how-to-solve-the-error-must-use-packagereference)